# Should a Baptist marry a Jehovah's witness?

Tags: marriage, jehovahs-witnesses, baptist

My fiancee is a Jehovah's witness.  We're supposed to be married in three weeks and I'm just now finding out about the mechanics of his religion. With my being a Baptist I can't help but think it's wrong but I won't judge him. I'd like to work past it  but I'm afraid of how this will work with our future children. I love him. I'm just worried. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Jehovah's Witnesses allowed to marry outside the faith?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/are-jehovahs-witnesses-allowed-to-marry-outside-the-faith)

Comment: "Should" is a question that we can't answer here. But you should be aware that Baptists are Trinitarian and Jehovah's Witnesses are non-Trinitarian and each consider the other to be heretics who believe in different gods and have a different gospel. Personally I definitely would reconsider such a marriage, especially if children is a possibility you're considering.

Comment: Definitely do talk to the church leaders from both of your churches. They can give you better advice than random people on the internet.

Comment: This film produced by Jehovah's Witnesses, ["What Is True Love?"](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=1102012819&srcid=share), shows some realistic consequences and explains how Jehovah's Witnesses view the matter.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the following article on what is (and is not allowed) when asking questions of Christianity Stack, because this question is likely to be closed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  If your fiancee is a baptised Witness in good standing then he should know better than to marry a Trinitarian Christian.  They say all Trinitarian Churches are part of the antichrist, Babylon the Great,

Comment: The fact that you and he are engaged to be married suggests that neither he or you are devout in your religion. Is he a baptized active publisher?  Does he attend meetings at the Kingdom Hall on a regular basis?  Have you and he talked about  the role your religion plays in your life now and how important you anticipate it to be in your futures?  If children bless your marriage will religion become more important to either you or him?  Would he be ok with you raising the kids as good little  Baptist’s?  Would you be fine with him raising the children as good little JWs?

Comment: Who is going to conduct the wedding ceremony?

Comment: What will the wedding supper be?

Comment: One should love the heavenly Bridegroom more than the earthly one.

Answer (score 3):

**Should a Baptist marry a Jehovah's Witness?**

That is a decision only you can take. You must ask yourself how important your Christian faith is to you and whether you are prepared to compromise your religious beliefs.

The U.K. Baptist church I became a member of (when I first became a Christian) is Trinitarian, unlike Jehovah's Witnesses who say the Trinity is pagan.  In 2015 they published an article in the Watchtower magazine saying that all Trinitarian churches are part of the antichrist. Does your fiancée go along with this view?  You need to ask him.  [(Source)](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/wp20150601/who-is-the-antichrist/)

You also need to ask yourself how important Christ Jesus is to you and whether your fiancée is prepared to respect your religious convictions and attend your church with a view to learning who Jesus Christ REALLY is - that He is not a created spirit called Michael the Archangel.

Please read this Christianity Stack question: [What is the Biblical basis for the belief that Michael is not Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75182/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-belief-that-michael-is-not-jesus)  Asked by Curiousdannii January 2020 – Biblical Basis for the belief that Michael is NOT Jesus

Choices we make in the here-and-now will have eternal consequences in the here-and-after.

Comment: I don't think most of our JW members here will be outraged if this question is closed or deleted, most know that proper question scoping is important.

Comment: @curiousdannii - fair comment and thanks for the edit.

Comment: Oh boy, ending with "Your salvation (and that of your fiancée) has eternal consequences." is quite chilling. The questions reads as: "It's all up to you, you need to decide what your priorities are and what compromises you're willing to make. ...but if you make the wrong choice, you'll suffer eternally in hell (and justifiable so), so enjoy your decision!)"

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - Please try to resist the temptation to put words into my mouth. I personally believe that belonging to a religious denomination is not what saves. All that matters is if you belong to Christ Jesus, not an organisation. I stand by my answer.

Comment: The last sentence may need a tweak

Comment: @Lesley  that’s much clearer.